# Grub run in which mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, bootloader, grub

I learn that when computer starts it is in real mode.
And kernel is responsible for switching mode from real to protected.
Ok , my question is Grub boot loader runs in real mode or in protected mode ?

Comment: Is there an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97946/grub-and-getting-into-real-mode-low-level-assembler-question? Including the link in the answer I mean.

Comment: No I gone through it already ... I don't get exact answer !

Comment: Perhaps the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821911/does-grub-switch-to-protected-mode

Comment: I would assume (makes an ass out of u and me, hehe) that the bootloader runs in Real mode since the kernel is actually responsible to switch from it to protected mode.

Comment: http://oss.sgi.com/LDP/HOWTO/Kernel-HOWTO/linux_boot_process.html and here http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#GNU_002fLinux they mention running in Real mode ("which involves loading another boot loader and jumping to it in real mode") before booting to protected mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Grub starts in real mode like any other software loaded at boot. It switches to protected mode for its run time (detecting HD, displaying menus etc.) and switches *back* into real mode before loading and running OS such as Linux that do not support multiboot protocol.

Answer (score 3):

See http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/kernel-boot-process for a detailed answer, but basically Grub does not switch to protected mode when running Linux. It loads the real-mode part of the kernel in low memory and let it do the switch itself (as required per the Linux Boot Protocol, http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.25.6/Documentation/i386/boot.txt)

However, Grub also supports the Multiboot Specification, which starts the loaded OS in protected mode. This is done for non-Linux kernels, like modern homebrew OSes for which the makers do not want to bother with the hassle of switching to protected mode.